# How do I use AXSD in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

In SQL Server you can use an XML datatype and map it to relational columns using an AXSD schema.

> Mapping between XML and relational
>   storage  By using an annotated schema
>   (AXSD), the XML is decomposed into
>   columns in one or more tables. This
>   preserves fidelity of the data at the
>   relational level. As a result, the
>   hierarchical structure is preserved
>   although order among elements is
>   ignored. The schema cannot be
>   recursive.

from [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522493.aspx)

However I cannot find any documentation on how to do this - or even a good page about AXSD.

Anybody got any good AXSD information. it seems very appropriate to what I want to do (temporarily use XML until i can migrate to something like nHibernate, but still allow a column view of certain pertanent data fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [this is the way to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258637(SQL.80).aspx) and [this is helpful too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172649(SQL.90).aspx).

And a [free book too](http://www.red-gate.com/specials/Ebooks/XSD_0409.htm)!

tip: search for 'annotated xsd schemass' and not AXSD!

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
  <xsd:element name="Employee" sql:relation="Employees" >
   <xsd:complexType>
     <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="FName"  
                     sql:field="FirstName" 
                     type="xsd:string" /> 
        <xsd:element name="LName"  
                     sql:field="LastName"  
                     type="xsd:string" />
     </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="EmpID" 
                       sql:field="EmployeeID" 
                       type="xsd:integer" />
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```